# ask the user to enter the studentID. Then you will open the text file and search for this ID. (C++)

Tags: c++

Struggling really hard with this, I need to enter an ID number thats in a text file and output the associated grades that are on the same line of the text file

This is the code I have, it prints the correct average but it prints the test scores of the next ID numeber

```
int searchID;
int studentID;
bool found = false;

double exam_1;
double exam_2;
double exam_3;
double average = 0;

cout << "Enter student ID to search in file " <<
    fileName << " : ";
//read searchID value
cin >> searchID;

//read data from file until the search id is found
while (fin >> studentID >> exam_1 >> exam_2
    >> exam_3 && !found)
{
    if (searchID == studentID)
    {
        average = (exam_1 + exam_2 + exam_3) / 3.0;
        found = true;
    }
}
//close the file stream,fin
fin.close();
//check if search id is found
if (found)
{
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Exam 1" << setw(10) << exam_1 << endl;
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Exam 2" << setw(10) << exam_2 << endl;
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Exam 3" << setw(10) << exam_3 << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2)
        << "Average : " << average << endl;
}
else
    cout << searchID << " student id is not found." << endl;

system("pause");
```

Comment: Unrelated: [Don't use `system("pause")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong)

Comment: What is `fileName`? What is `fin`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, preferably one which shows all variables and how they are initialized and if possible just for us to copy-paste to be able to replicate the problem you have.

Comment: A hint about your problem though: Learn about [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and think about how the order you do things in the loop condition might be affected by it.

Comment: `while (fin >> studentID >> exam_1 >> exam_2
    >> exam_3 && !found)`  -- Read that line out loud.  What does it tell you?  Read a new line, and if you found something previously, don't loop.  Is that what you want, to read a new line in, destroying the previous results?  Shouldn't you check if you found something first,, and if not found, then read the new line?  It all boils down to simple logic -- it's really nothing to have a struggle with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are correct, sorry I didnt notice, and yes I was Struggling which is perfectly okay

Answer (score 0):

Your got the loop condition wrong. Lets say one iteration found the `ID`, `found` is set to true, then for the next iteration the condition is evaluated:

```
while (fin >> studentID >> exam_1 >> exam_2 >> exam_3 && !found)
```

No matter what is the value of `found` you read the next entry in the file. Change it to

```
while (!found && fin >> studentID >> exam_1 >> exam_2 >> exam_3)
```

`&&` short-circuits, ie when `!found` is `false`, the rest of the condition is not evaluated.